# Estou tentando criar um comando de pokemon em javascript discord.js v12

Tags: javascript

Eu fiz o comando tava tudo certinho, ae a versão do *discord.js* foi para a v12 e mudou tudo e agora meu comando não funciona mais

fica dando erro :  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined`

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Você tem 15 segundos para adivinhar! Quem é esse Pokémon!')
.setImage(pokem.imageURL)

const msg = message.channel.send({ embed });
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
const attempts =  msg.channel.messages(filter, { time: 15000});

if (!attempts || !attempts.size) {
  msg.delete();

  return message.channel.send(`Você demorou muito para responder. O pokemon era ${pokem.name}.`);
}
```

Comment: já leu a documentação da v12 e o que mudou?

Comment: `Channel` não tem a propriedade `messages`, leia https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel